# (Lift) What's the purpouse of dflt : Box[String] parameter in JsCmds.ReplaceOptions case class

Tags: scala, lift

There's a case class in JsCmds named ReplaceOptions. The signature of it's constructor is:

```
ReplaceOptions (select: String, opts: List[(String, String)], dflt: Box[String]) extends JsCmd with Product
```

And the scaladoc description provided is:

> Update a Select with new Options
>
> select: is the id of the select html component that will be updated
>
> opts: is a List with tuples that represents the value:text of the
>   options that will be set in the select component.

What is dflt intended for? If I simply use `Box[String]("Test")` it works but I just cant get why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is meant to select the default value of the select. For exemple if you update the options to be `List(("choice1", "Apple"), ("choice2", "Orange"), ("choice3", "Banana"))`.

Then you can choose either "Apple", "Orange" or "Banana" as default value by respectively setting dflt as `Full("choice1")`, `Full("choice2")` or `Full("choice3")`.

This way, when the user loads the page (or in the case of `ReplaceOptions`, when the options are replaced), an adapted default value is selected.